# How come the Green kryptonite didn't kill baby Clark on the way to Smallville?

Tags: dc, superman, smallville

We know that Clark Kent (Superman) is "allergic" to green Kryptonite. His blood "boils" around it and it may be fatal to him. He first came to Smallville in 1984 along with the debris from Krypton which contains green Kryptonite.

We see that the ship cannot block green Kryptonite in the season 2 finale "Exodus". Also the ship lacked the power to neutralize green Kryptonite as it did in "Visage" since during the entire space journey the ship had enough time and was in close enough proximity to green Kryptonite to neutralize all of it but this didn't happen as Kryptonite still landed in Smallville.

Therefore during the entire space journey, the baby Kal-El was in close proximity to green Kryptonite. **Shouldn't he have died due to the continual expos**ure?

Comment: "He first came to Smallville in 2001" - I think Smallville was first shown on TV in 2001, and was set in the present day. Thus, in-universe, Clark must have arrived in Smallville around 1986.

Comment: I would say that because Clarke was not yet acclimatised to Earth, the Kryptonite wouldn't have harmed him. Kryptonite certainly wasn't poisonous on Krypton and it is logical to assume that the ship had life support replicating Krypton rather than Earth.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have never seen *Smallville* (although I know very well about Superman), So my answer to the question will be in accordance with what I read about *kryptonite* on [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kryptonite) wikipedia article. Particularly this part:

> In **Smallville**, Green Kryptonite is used to counter the effects of any other form of
>   Kryptonite that may enter a Kryptonian's system, for example a kiss with red Kryptonite laced lipstick or Gem Kryptonite dust in the eyes. In **Lois and Clark**, a green Kryptonite bullet is also used to bring Superman back in control when his powers become over-amped by red Kryptonite and a sample of Kryptonite was used to starve out a Kryptonian virus.

It can be inferred that *Green Kryptonite* is harmless to Superman (or any other Kryptonian) when used with other form of kryptonite.

When he first came to Smallville in 1984, the debris that came along with him would surely have had a mixture of all forms of Kryptonite and thus, green kryptonite would have been harmless to him.

This all is of course an assumption but I think it is kind of logical.

Comment: What about the neutralizing effect of the ship on Green kryptonite?

Comment: @Adeetya: For my answer, I assumed that if somehow ship was not able to neutralize the effect of Green Kryptonite, how was baby Superman safe from it. My apologies, but as I said I haven't seen Smallville to be an expert on the topic.

Answer (score 4):

It was simple enough , the ship left before krypton exploded , so he was a safe distance ahead untill he slowed down reaching the earths atmosphere .

Comment: And why the downvotes ?i just watched the first episode and the flashback episodes and the ship is always ahead of the meteor rocks during the journey .

Comment: Downvotes maybe due to fact that the ship and the meteor arrived at Smallville together.. also were seen heading to Earth together..

Answer (score 3):

Kryptonite ONLY has  its weakening affect on Kryptonians  in earths atmosphere. Otherwise, every Kryptonian on Krypton itself would have died. And Kryptonite only has an affect on "superpowered" Kryptonians. When Clark doesn't have any powers (episode "Blue") there is no sign of him weakening. I hope that answers your question completely.

Comment: This is a good (in-universe) answer. It would be vastly improved by backing up your assertions with a quote, either from within the show or by someone involved in the writing.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not super-familiar with Smallville, but two possibilities spring to mind:

1. Whilst travelling from Krypton, perhaps the ship wasn't actually close enough to *all* of the green Kryptonite to neutralise it. The debris came from the destruction of an entire planet, so the meteorite shower produced could have been pretty big.
2. During transit, the ship may have had some sort of energy-based field that deflected radiation ([there's a lot of radiation in space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Health_threat_from_cosmic_rays)), which was turned off once the ship landed. This could have shielded baby Clark from the Kryptonite's effects.

Comment: In one episode, the ship neutralized Lana's meteor rock necklace turning it from green to clear. It's possible the ship did the same thing with meteor fragments that got too close to it in space. `http://smallville.wikia.com/wiki/Lana%27s_necklace`

However--kryptonite does affect the ship, as it reacted badly to the kyrptonite key that was fashioned by Lionel Luthor to fit in it. `http://smallville.wikia.com/wiki/Kryptonite_key`

Comment: You're just repeating what is said in the question with a few added links to Smallville wikia.. .:P

Comment: @Paul D. Waite.. The kryptonte had to be very close to the ship otherwise all that would not have landed in Smallville.. but would have landed all over the US.. 
Due to no guidance systems for the rocks :P , even a small angular change could have changed their course by hundreds of miles.. therefore they would all have to be nearly parallel with respect to each other and would have to be very close to one another in order to land in the same town..

Comment: @Adeetya: "The kryptonte had to be very close to the ship otherwise all that would not have landed in Smallville." Not necessarily. The ship could have been followed by Kryptonite on the same trajectory, but a couple of miles behind it.

Comment: In the Pilot all the kryptonite and the ship were seen heading towards Earth together... and also that couple of miles would then make a time difference of almost an hour which we see did not happen..

Comment: "that couple of miles would then make a time difference of almost an hour" - You're saying the meteorite fragments were travelling at a little over 2 miles an hour?!

Answer (score 2):

The interior of the ship would have had to have been shielded against all manner of cosmic radiation to protect not-yet-invulnerable baby Kal-El, so that must have protected him from the Kryptonite radiation as well.

Comment: What about the neutralizing effect of the ship on Green kryptonite?

Answer (score 0):

May be green kryptonite is effective only on adults of Krypton.

Comment: Do you have canon support? If not it's not an answer, just a random guess

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is that Green Kryptonite only "works its magic" in a livable atmosphere such as Earth (or Krypton for that matter). In other words, maybe it is activated by oxygen or some other element found in the atmospheres where it has affect. We know that Kal-El is powered by the Earth's sun, from various sources, including other answers here - so maybe that contributes to it.

Comment: What about the neutralizing effect of the ship on Green kryptonite?

Answer (score 0):

Superman gains his powers from the earths sun.  This is countered by the effects of Kryptonite from Krypton.  At the time of his arrival at earth, and until he became empowered by the sun of earth he would have been a normal Kryptonian, and immune to the effects of Kryptonite.  The ship that neutralized the powers of the Kryptonite may only activate this ability in response to its programmed mission of protecting Cal El.  With no threat at the time of entry there was nothing to neutralize.  When we was older, and the threat of Kryptonite on Cal El presented, the threat was neutralized.

Comment: The ship was programmed to protect only itself as seen in the Season 2 Finale

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you answered your own question (i.e. the ship protected him)  But here goes anyway:
Smallville (TV) is not considered a part of the DC Superman canon.
Second, we have the old problem of different writers interpreting how the ship and Clark's powers behave (i.e. inconsistencies).
Third, Smallville (a large portion of the town) was hit by a meteor shower but not all the debris was Kryptonite and more importantly the ship **couldn't have been near all of the Kryptonite**.

Think about it; a tiny ship VS a significantly larger debris field?  The ship isn't going to "win".  So, the ship will simply just avoid any collisions or dangers.

And people had to actively look for Kryptonite and dig it up.
And the ship obviously had to protect Clark from the rigors of space flight and that would go for Kryptonite as well.
So, why isn't Clark dead? Because the ship protected him in transit.
Why didn't the ship neutralize all the Kryptonite? Because it wasn't near all the Kryptonite.
And the ship did alter it's course to land near the Kent farm. The meteor shower *can't* alter it's course.

The out of universe answer is there will always be Kryptonite around as it is the only MacGuffin that can quickly slow down, disable or kill Superman.